# Detection of custom keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard, driver

I have a X7 G800V keyboard with 15 custom keys. The problem is they are not detected in anything but the software that comes with the keyboard which is a real cave eat since I can't use them in photoshop, word or any other program. Is there any way to make them detectable? I am open for ideas even if they include writing my own driver, although I may need some tips on that but still I am open for learning. After all the guys from A4Tech do it with their software and I think they are not even installing any drivers.

PS: I am sorry for this not being an exactly programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the OS doesn't support these keys, I don't see a way to process them, unless you can configure your driver to communicate them to the OS as some other key. For instance if you press key `Special1`, the driver tells the operating system to process it as `Play`.

Or you might consider to write a driver yourself, if the driver is open-source, or an API is available.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I can easily remap the keys to other that windows can detect using the software that comes with the keyboard but this is not what I am looking for. There has to be a way to enable the use of those aditional keys. There are other keyboards with custom keys that are detectable in windows by using some kind of driver provided with them.

Comment: Oh and writing my own driver IS an option but problem is that neither is the software/driver open-source, neither is there an API.
PS: Just because the people at A4Tech are too lazy to make a proper driver for their keyboard doesn't mean that I have to be too :D

Comment: No offense, but I wouldn't even consider buying a special keyboard without the driver at least providing an API. Unless of course it's an ordinary one without any special functions. :)

Comment: None taken xD ... the keyboard did have a "driver" disk but it contained only the software for making macros and stuff. Also at that time that is what I wanted and I didn't expect that I would be able to use the keys for anything else but macros. But today it just came to my mind that this may be actually possible and I am off to stackoverflow :)

Comment: I found this http://www.codeforge.com/article/177543. It looks like I may be able to edit it to add some more keys but I have no idea how I can do that. Sorry just realized that I can't download it. I hate such sites.

Comment: If you look at http://www.codeforge.com/read/177543/mckeyboard.cpp__html, you see how they handle KeyDown events... Perhaps you can slightly modify them?

Comment: Hmm yes. Should be it. I also found that I can get the original driver  source code from windows device driver development kit. Oh and yes the keyboard uses the windows driver(sooo stupid for not mentioning this initially :D)